# Proving that the root subspace of order $r$ is $A$-invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Suppose we have an operator $A$ acting on a finite $n$-dimensional space $E$. My book defines the root subspace of order $r$ (corresponding to eigen-value $\lambda$) as the space:

$W^r = Ker(A-\lambda I)^r$, with $r = 1,2,..,n$

The book continually mentions (without proof) that such spaces are all $A$ invariant. That is, for any $x \in W^r$, it must be that $Ax \in W^r$. I don't doubt this in anyway, but I'm unsure how to actually prove it.

Obviously if $r = 1$ then $W^r$ is just the standard characteristic subspace corresponding to eigen-value $\lambda$ and so it follows that:

$x \in W^1$

$=>$ $Ax = \lambda x$

$=>$ $A(Ax) = \lambda^2 x = \lambda Ax$

$=> Ax \in W^1$

And so $W^1$ is $A$-invariant. But for powers larger than $1$ I'm unsure how to prove this since dealing with the power $r$ requires a binomial expansion?

If I was to use a binomial expansion then I figure I could do something like this:

My attempt:

$(A - \lambda I)^r Ax = (\sum_{k=0}^r$ $r \choose k$ $A^{r-k} (\lambda I)^r)Ax$

$=A (\sum_{k=0}^r$ $r \choose k$ $A^{r-k} (\lambda I)^r) x$  since $A$ is commutative with itself (*)

$=A (A-\lambda I)^r x$

$=A 0$ since $x \in W^r$

$=0$ since $A$ is an operator and as such $A(\alpha x) = \alpha A(x)$

Is this a correct proof? I'm unsure if the step (*) is valid.